# how to pass list in the constructor using Windsor castle

Tags: list, parameters, castle-windsor

I have got `IController` which implements 2 `ControllerA`, `ControllerB`

say I have a class:

```
public class MyComponent
{
   public MyComponent(List<IController> constrollers)
   {
      _constrollers = constrollers;
   }
}
```

in order to instantiate this class there is a way in windsor castle with using XML

```
<parameters>
   <constrollers>
      <list>
         <item>controllerA</item>
         <item>controllerB</item>
      </constrollers>
   </info>
</parameters>
```

but how can I achieve it programatically, using Fluent ?

Comment: BTW that code doesn't compile, and that XML is invalid...

Answer (score 2):

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyComponent>()
 .ServiceOverrides(new { controllers = new[] { "controllerA", "controllerB" } }));
```